# Adverse Events for Avastin - vision issues

Tags: data-request, openfda, medical

I need a list of the adverse events for Avastin drug. I mainly would like to see a list of adverse events concerning vision issues.

Answer (score 2):

This API call should help you get started with all adverse event (AE) reports involving Avastin:

```
https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=brand_name:avastin&limit=100
```

but be sure to read through the comprehensive docs at https://open.fda.gov/drug/event/reference/ to see if you want to be searching for a subset of this data set which is where Avastin was the `suspect drug`. I am not 100% sure that would be possible through the API since you want to limit your search to a nested object.

To search for only AE reports where a certain AE related to vision was reported, you'll want to look through the list of all AEs from the above API call (`https://api.fda.gov/drug/event.json?search=brand_name:avastin&count=patient.reaction.reactionmeddrapt.exact`) and then filter based on those.

You can also use a more user-friendly tool that Brian Norris and I built at http://researchae.com. Here's a hyperlink to [only Avastin AE reports](http://www.researchae.com/drugevent?from_date=1900-01-01&to_date=2014-11-17&from_age=&to_age=&search=&country=GLOBALLY&patientsex=&manufacturername=&drugbrandname=avastin&druggenericname=&medicinalproduct=&reactionmeddrapt=&drugclass=&drugindication=&indsubmit=&productndc=&safetyreportid=).

Hope this helps and good luck!